# Why Led lights with 3 AA batteries and not in pairs?

Tags: batteries, nimh

Im trying to purchase some lamp powered by batteries, I want to use the typical 2100 mAh AA rechargeable 1.2V batteries to avoid purchasing tons and tons of one use AA simple batteries.

I already have an old lantern working with 4 AA 1.2V batteries, not led, I can use a 4 pack rechargeable batteries, but it seems that it consumes the power even if its not turned on, so I decided to get some new led wall lantern or something like those closet lights on amazon.

But there seems not to be any of those lights out there powered by a pair number of AA batteries (2 or 4 batteries), every light is 3 AA, 6 AA, and more and more 3 AA powered.

Why always are 3? I can't use rechargeable batteries on that because when I can't recharge 3 at same time, and if I try to recharge those 3 used batteries with a 4th already charged battery, then it does not charge properly.

IS the "industry" doing this only to force people to buy tons of simple AA batteries or is there any specific electronics issue with pair powered batteries on leds?

Comment: Actually an 18650 single LiPo cell is a better voltage match for driving LEDs with a voltage range from 3.7 to 3.3 with a suitable buck CC regulator

Comment: It's "Dollar Store"  flashlights that use Alkaline

Comment: Did you ever consider the difference between the voltage of the batteries 2x batteries = 2.4V 3x batteries = 3.6V "The typical forward voltage of a white LED is in the range of 3V to 5V"

Comment: Thank you a lot to everyone with your great answers, I'm sorry I cant mark every answer as "this answer solved my question" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rechargeable batteries are still a bit of a niche product despite being around for decades in a consumer-friendly form.  It's simpler to design for alkalines (or zinc-carbon etc).

There is actually an advantage to running a torch on primary (non-rechargeable) cells -- self discharge.  As you've noticed NiMH cells discharge on the shelf, which isn't much use when you want a torch that will be ready when it's needed, months from now.  Low self-discharge cells are available but cost more and have a lower capacity.

Faced with a similar problem here's a solution I've used (going back 25 years for Lego motors and ever since): get 8 identical batteries, charge them all.  When you change the batteries, recharge 2, and keep the 3rd flat one until you next change the batteries, at which point you'll have an even number of flat ones.  This isn't perfect due to self-discharge but it's close enough.

The lower nominal voltage of NiMH (1.2V vs 1.5V for alkaline) means you might be able to get away with running 4 rather than 3 in series (4.8 vs 4.5 V) and very slightly shorteing the life of the LEDs. *But* NiMH cells have a lower internal resistance, and if that resistance is a major part of the resistance to limit the current into the LEDs (as it often is in cheap designs with coin cells, but less often in AA-based designs) you'll probably fry the LEDs quite quickly.

Comment: Alkalines and zinc-carbon sag under load, so all those "1.5V" gizmos work great with Ni-XX because they don't sag from their 1.2V. However, adding 33% more voltage is dangerous. In my experience the only devices that don't work well with rechargeables are the ultra-low power like clocks and tv remotes.

Comment: @Agent_L, "dangerous" is too strong in the context of cheap things like torches.  It's often not easy to get an extra cell in there anyway

Comment: I meant dangerous to the gizmo, not to the operator. Things are cheap, but that's still no reason to burn them.

Comment: @Agent_L OK, but I've run cheap bike lights designed for 2xAA (~2.4V--3V) off single 14500 Li-ion rechargeables at 3.7V--4.2V for long periods (every dark morning/evening for a few years, for up to an hour each time) without harm.  That's the same proportional change.

Comment: Yeah, by "dangerous" I meant it that bad things may happen. Or may not. It's perfectly fine to try it, if you can live with loss of the gadget. But I would certainly not try it on a $50 MagLite.

Comment: @Agent_L that's fair. Maglites, to me, are incandescent (showing my age there I guess) and running N NiCd/NiMH cells with the bulb for N-1 alkalines was common practice to maximise output at the expense of a few more bulb changes.  My medium-power torches (e.g. 200 lumen) are only cheap too, but use an LED driver with a wide-range input (1.2--4V so they'll run off NiMH AAs or 14500s)

Comment: I've seen both incadescent and LED Maglites in a shop few days ago. It was just meant as an example of an expensive LED torch.

Answer (score 3):

Because white LEDs have a forward voltage of 3.2 - 3.4V.

Comment: and high power LEDs or more efficient LEDs have lower ESR thus lower Vf typically 3V in >=3W

Comment: although none of the 5mm white LEDs I have bought in the last few years have been >=3.2V at >16Cd in 50k lots

Comment: Are you sure? I have a "hand" flashlight with one led (energizer) working with 2 AAA 900 mAh 1.2V rechargeable batteries, and then I have another flashlight panel with 31 leds working with 3 AAA batteries 1.5V.

Comment: @DarkDogma3D The energizer torch may have some sort of boost converter inside. The 31 LEDs will be connected in parallel

Answer (score 1):

The torch could be manufactured using four  batteries but the voltage would then need to be dropped, so extra production costs and if the voltage is dropped through a resistor you get a small energy lose in heat at the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Any decently designed one with the least bit of electronic "smarts" can operate  from a single cell, or two cells (by using a boost converter) but cheap ones operate stupidly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffbkvU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a nice LED retrofit for a 2-AA flashlight, which incorporates a boost converter/ current regulator and LED into a package that fits where the old bulb fit - unlike cheap 3-cell units, it stays bright throughout most of the battery life, too. As a result of that design it works quite well on NiMH cells, too.

On the very crude end you can find single cell circuits using a blocking oscillator configuration which are popular hobbyist plaything (I've played with them myself) but those are probably not the best choice for a well-designed flashlight.

Comment: see, for example, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43027/low-voltage-oscillator-for-joule-thief/43041#43041